# Current location (currentposition) function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

Currentposition function not working, `Alert2` is been show and even then the map doesnt appear. Please help me out, I am not able to find a solution

```
if (navigator.geolocation){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            // Set the user's position
            userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            alert("currentloc1 : "+ userLocation);
            mapObject.setCenter(userLocation);
            setUserMarker();
            // Get the user's address if possible
            geoCodeObject.geocode({ 'latLng': userLocation }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    $("#location_details").html(results[0].formatted_address);
                    userAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                }
                else {

                        var errormessage="There were no hospitals found at the location. Please provide another location.";
                        alertBox(errormessage);
                        $("body").css("cursor", "default");

                }
            });
        },
        function () {
            userLocation = locationPune;
            alert("currentloc2 : "+ userLocation);
        },
        {
            timeout: 5000
        }

    );
}else{

    userLocation = locationPune;
   alert("currentloc3 : "+ userLocation);
}
```

Comment: How are you showing the map?

Comment: "function () {
            userLocation = locationPune;
            alert("currentloc2 : "+ userLocation);
        }," this is alert 2..

Comment: atoztoa.. i m using 2 different functions to set location in map, one is current position which is not working properly and another one is set location which works completely fine

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: no i m not getting any error in console

Comment: Have you tried `alert(position)`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have 5 second timeout. Try a little more:

```
{
    timeout: 15000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that the arguments are?

```
getCurrentPosition(showLocation, ErrorHandler, options);
```

The second alert would only be called if there is an error condition.